# Android app crashing after resigning

Tags: java, android, security, certificate, signature

I am currently working with an application that seems to check its own signature upon startup.
Hence, after resigning the .apk with my own key, i get an error since its not the official signature.
The app gets its own signature by calling 
`getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), GET_SIGNATURES).signatures[xy];`.
I already tried to override those signatures with the original signatures after every such call, yet the app complains that it has been altered.

So, apart from the result of `signatures[xy].toByteArray()` or, to be more precise, the byteArray content of `Signature.mSignature`, which is returned upon every `toByteArray()`-call, is there anything i am missing which could be used to detect an alternation of the app?

Comment: what's value of xy

Comment: Post logcat error here.

Comment: THanks for your anwsers. XY is, in most cases, 0

Comment: And the app does not crash, it only, somehow, detects that it has been altered

Comment: So if I understand you right, you want to add a signature, and check it on start-up? In other words, what you are really asking is: ***"How can I make my app verify it's own integrity on startup?"***. Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what i am asking is **How can i make an app prevent from checking its Integrity**, athough even that misses my point.